# change Wifi key

Tags: wireless, password

I was trying to connect to wifi on ubuntu 12.4 when I accidentally typed in the wrong wifi key. Now I cannot seem to find how to change it. I've already tried going to the edit connections. The connection I am trying to connect to is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Edit Connections... -> Wireless -> Add**, now add your wifi network details like **SSID** and WiFi key from **Wireless Security** tab.